# Перекрыть андроидовскую активити для вызовов на свою

Tags: java, android

Нужно создать программу, которая при входящем-исходящем вызове показывает мою активити, а не стандартную андроидовскую.

Первая активити имеет кнопки старт и стоп для запуска и остановки сервиса, который проверяет в каком состоянии сейчас телефон, и если он не находится в режиме ожидания (то есть если `getCallState() != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`) то должна запускаться другая активити и она же должна быть во время разговора. А она не запускается. Запускается только если во время разговора еще раз старт нажать. А надо чтоб появлялась сама еще во время вызова. Гугл советовал эти строки, но они не помогают

```
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
<action android:name="ru.startandroid.develop.p0972servicebindserver.MyService" />
<action android:name="com.lowveld.ucs.action.INDIRECT_CALL"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Думаю, скорей всего, код сервиса не там, где надо написала. Но если не в `onStartCommand`, то где? Последние пару раз вообще бесконечный цикл туда влепила, чтоб наверняка проверяло все время, но не помогло.

Может еще в манифесте что-то надо дописать?